# Rename 1 Column in every dataframe in a List

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename one column in a dataframe list.

```
my_list <- list(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5), data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5))

[[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

[[2]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

lapply(my_list, function(x){
  k <- my_list[[ x ]]
  # set 2nd column to a new name
  names(k)[2] <- "NEW COLUMN"
  # return
})
```

This is the output I hope to achieve

```
[[1]]
  a NEW COLUMN
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

[[2]]
  a NEW COLUMN
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

However, my lapply does not seem to work. The error code is below:

> Error in my_list[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Answer (score 1):

We are looping through the `list` itself and not its index.  So, in the anonymous call, 'x' is the value i.e. the element data.frame of the `list`.

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {names(x)[2] <- "NEW COLUMN"; x})
```

---

Suppose, if we loop through the sequence, the OP's code would be right

```
lapply(seq_along(my_list), function(i) {
      k <- my_list[[ i ]] # extracted the list element
      names(k)[2] <- "NEW COLUMN"
      k
     })
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the seq_along function! (: